# C# Which synchronization class to use?

Tags: c#, multithreading, synchronization

I have the following synchronization problem to solve:

Multiple threads occationally check if a certain condition is fulfilled. If a checking thread finds that the condition is *not* fulfilled, it must block itself until another thread fulfills the condition and thereby releases all waiting/blocked threads.

Does .NET have such an out-of-the-box syncrhonizing class that I can use? Or will I have to build my own synchronization class on top of something else?

What I need is a simple semaphore-like class with only these two methods:

- **bool Wait( TimeSpan maxTimeToWait )** //blocks any caling thread until another thread calls **Signal()** (or timeout - the return value will show what happened)
- **void Signal()** //releases all waiting threads.

Regards, Martin.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?

Comment: This sounds like a job for the [Monitor class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Almost all synchronızatıon primitives can be used for this, but it is not clear what you *really* want to do. Maybe there can be better ways than saying *use this*.  (For ex, `Multiple threads occationally check if a certain condition is fulfilled` may not be needed and can purely be imlplemented with sync primitives)

Comment: What I need is the behavior of the **AutoResetEvent** class, except that I want *all* waiting threads released on a single call to **Set()** (and not only **one** thread, like is the case with **AutoResetEvent**).

Answer (score 1):

[EventWaitHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.eventwaithandle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) sounds like what you are looking for. Keep in mind that as you get into such specific implementations, you might be better off making a wrapper class to do what you want by hooking into the disparate .NET classes that do the parts of what you want.

By using an auto-resetting behavior, you can make a handle which is fired every time something about said condition *changes*, and then perform a `while` loop against the condition

```
EventWaitHandle ConditionHandle
//...
while(!condition)
    ConditionHandle.WaitOne();
```

Answer (score 0):

[AutoResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does what you're asking for.

Ah. I misunderstood what you were asking. A ManualResetEvent or a ManualResetSlim will let all the blocking threads through, but you'll need to reset the MRE to unsignalled manually.

Comment: According to documentation the AutoResetEvent will only release one waiting thread on a call to Set(). I need all waiting threads to be released.

Comment: @MartinChristiansen Actually "Sets the state of the event to signaled, allowing one **or more** waiting threads to proceed. (Inherited from EventWaitHandle.)"

Comment: @Aravol: In the remarks you can read: "Calling Set signals AutoResetEvent to release a waiting thread. AutoResetEvent remains signaled until **a single** waiting thread is released, and then automatically returns to the non-signaled state. If no threads are waiting, the state remains signaled indefinitely.". It was because of this I assumed that only one waiting thread would be released.

Comment: I had to unmark this answer as the one that solved my problem. In fact, my problem is still unsolved. The problem with the AutoResetEvent is that it indeed only releases **one** thread every time you cal the Set() method - and there is no way to determine how many threads are waiting. I really don't know what to do?

Comment: I misunderstood your original question. Updated to point you towards the class that doesn't automatically reset itself.